# linux run jar on startup after mysql is running

Tags: startup

Is there a way to run a jar at startup on CentOS 6.5 but only after MySQL is running?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Make sure Java is installed and make a startup script that starts after MySQL. You should at least provide some more info about the version of CentOS  you are running because it makes a difference how things are started.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for you reply. I have CentOS 6.5 , I already have Java installed, but I don't know how to write the script.

Comment: Don't you know how to write the script, or don't you know how to invoke a script after MySQL is running, or both?

Comment: don't know how to invoke the script after MySQL is running.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way is to add a command that starts your application at the bottom of the file `/etc/rc.local`. This file is executed last of the `rc` files during the startup process, and normally the MySQL server should be running by then.